# How to mock elasticsearch.helpers.bulk

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocking

I am testing a class that uses `bulk` to index some documents.

Here is my code:

```
import mock
import unittest
import json

from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

from ingestion.ingestor import Ingestor

class TestIngestor(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ingestor = Ingestor()

    @mock.patch("elasticsearch.helpers.bulk", mock.MagicMock(return_value=True))
    def test_ingestor(self):
        with open("tests/data/sample_payload.json", "r") as reader:
            sample_messages = json.loads(reader.read())["Messages"]

        actions = self.ingestor.ingest(sample_messages)

        self.assertEqual(len(actions), 10)
```

However, the mocking does not seem to work... when I run it, I get a long list of connection refused errors.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my patch was wrong... Here is how I fixed it:

```
@mock.patch("elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk", 
             mock.MagicMock(return_value={"items":[]}))
```

Comment: Faced similar issues while mocking this lib. Quite hard to get the paths right because of how modules are imported (even more with `_async` ressources). Say I am using `from elasticsearch.helpers import async_bulk` what would the path be?