# mock elasticsearch.helpers.async_bulk using pytest

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mocking

### Context

I successfully managed to mock various methods of this lib

```py
async with AsyncElasticsearch(what,ever) as session:
    patterns = await session.cat.templates(format="json")
```

using

```py
mocker.patch(
        "elasticsearch._async.client.cat.CatClient.templates", side_effect=mock.AsyncMock(return_value={"some":"payload"})
    )
```

### Issue

However, when it comes to `async_bulk` used in the very same manner

```py
async with AsyncElasticsearch(what,ever) as session:
    await async_bulk(
       session,
       self._rec_to_actions(item, index),
       stats_only=bool(logger.getEffectiveLevel() != logging.DEBUG),
       ignore_status=(200),
       max_retries=2,
       )
```

the following does not work.

```py
mocker.patch("elasticsearch._async.helpers.async_bulk", side_effect=mock.AsyncMock(return_value=None))
```

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:9200 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9200)]) caused by: ClientConnectorError(Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:9200 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9200)])
```

I tried several paths (`elasticsearch.helpers.async_bulk`) but without much effect. I do not understand why. [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602105/how-to-mock-elasticsearch-helpers-bulk)

### Environnement

- python 3.9.7
- elasticsearch 7.14
- pytest 6.2.5